# Need help for my wheel size

Tags: wheels

If my tyre size is 27 by 1/4. what size of wheel do I need. I just bought a second hand road bike and will need to repair it. But one of my problems is what size my wheels are, 700c or 27 by 1/4.

Comment: Well, there is no such thing as a 27 x 1/4, so I presume you have a 27 x 1-1/4, a fairly common old "road" tire.  If the tires are 27 then so are the rims -- 700c tires *will not* fit (at least not very well).  You may have to look around a bit, but 27 x 1-1/4 tires are still readily available.  For more than you ever wanted to know about tire sizes, see [Sheldon](http://sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html).

Comment: Note that if you have 27" wheels, you can often just move your brake pads down a few mm and stick a 700c wheel+tire on. But 27" tires are still made and so are the wheels (by say, velo orange).

Comment: Don't buy wheels to fit the tire.  Wheel is the metal part and tire is the rubber part.  Wheel is more expensive than the tire.  If the wheels are OK then just buy tires (and tubes) to fit them.

Comment: @Batman Often, but not always.

Comment: @jimirings when the options are 700x or 27", that's the right call. But buying new wheels for a 600B bike might be worth while.

Comment: @Nui I think you may have misread Blam's comment as being mine.

Answer (score 1):

You have 27inch wheels, and you can still buy tubes, tires and even new wheels.